# Como fazer um regex para pegar da barra (/) até o _, ou seja eu quero apenas os dígitos antes do _

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

> /dir/user/Desktop/zip/**1**_0.zip
>
> /dir/user/Desktop/zip/**2**_0.zip

Eu quero capturar apenas os números em negrito. Estou fazendo o seguinte e enviando a um `foreach` mas não está capturando certo:

```
preg_match_all('/\/(0-9,_)\//', $data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso mais simples (só existe uma ocorrência de números em cada string), você poderia fazer:

```
$data = <<<DATA
/dir/user/Desktop/zip/1_0.zip
/dir/user/Desktop/zip/2_0.zip
DATA;

if (preg_match_all('/\/(\d+)_/', $data, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[1] as $m) {
        echo $m.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

A regex considera uma barra (`\/`), depois [um ou mais](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) [dígitos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) (`\d+`) e o caractere `_`.

Os dígitos estão entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), assim todos eles ficam disponíveis na posição 1 do array de *matches* (é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex, portanto é o primeiro grupo de captura, e por isso eles ficam na posição 1). A saída é:

```
1
2
```

---

Se tiver outros números na string (por exemplo, `/dir/user/3_Desktop/zip/1_0.zip`) e você só quer pegar o último de cada string, basta deixar a regex mais específica:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\/(\d+)_[^\/]*zip/', $data, $matches)) {
    ....
```

No caso, adicionei `[^\/]*zip`:

- zero ou mais caracteres [que não sejam](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) a barra (`[^\/]*`)
- a string `zip`

Assim, se a string for `/dir/user/3_Desktop/zip/1_0.zip`, ele ignora o número 3 e só pega o 1.

---

A sua regex tinha `0-9,_`, que é literalmente "o número zero, seguido de hífen, seguido do número 9, vírgula e `_`". Usar `0-9` como intervalo só funciona em [classes de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (entre colchetes): `[0-9]`.

---

Se o formato sempre é o que foi indicado, outra opção (sem regex) é simplesmente ["explodir tudo"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$partes = explode('/', '/dir/user/Desktop/zip/1_0.zip');
$valor = explode('_', end($partes))[0];
echo $valor; // 1
```

No caso, eu quebro a string usando a barra como delimitador, e pego a última parte com [`end`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php). Em seguida, quebro de novo, usando `_` como delimitador e pego a primeira parte, que corresponde ao número.

Outra opção é:

```
$partes = explode('/', '/dir/user/Desktop/zip/1_0.zip');
$ultima = array_values(array_slice($partes, -1))[0];
$valor = explode('_', $ultima)[0];
echo $valor; // 1
```

Comment: Muito boa explicacao,obrigado pela ajuda!!!